# Error "sigemptyset was not declared in this scope" when using C+11 and Newlib

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin, signals, newlib

We are catching compiler errors when using `sigemptyset` on Cygwin under Newlib. The error occurs with a C++ compiler, but only when `-std=XXX` is used. Without a standard option, the test program compiles and executes as expected.

The test program is below, and the Cygwin header of interest follows. I don't see anything suspicious in the Cygwin header.

I've tried tricks like `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`. I've also tried tricks like using the global and `std` namespaces. Related, see [What does -D_XOPEN_SOURCE do/mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5378778/608639) and [Namespace issues in c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13040139/608639).

What is causing the compile failure and how do I fix it?

---

```cxx
$ cat ~/test.cxx 
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct sigaction new_handler;
    return sigemptyset(&new_handler.sa_mask);
}
```

Without a `-std=XXX`, it results in:

```
$ g++ -c test.cxx
$
```

With a `-std=XXX`, it results in:

```
$ g++ -std=c++03 -c test.cxx
test.cxx: In function int main(int, char**):
test.cxx:6:44: error: sigemptyset was not declared in this scope
  return sigemptyset(&new_handler.sa_mask);
```

And when trying to use `sigemptyset` in the global namespace:

```
$ g++ -std=c++03 -c test.cxx
test.cxx: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cxx:6:12: error: ‘::sigemptyset’ has not been declared
     return ::sigemptyset(&new_handler.sa_mask);
            ^
```

[Things get worse when using `-std=gnu++03` and friends](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20665).

Comment: My *guess*? When you use plain C++ standard without GNU extensions, you need to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` before including `<signal.h>`.

Comment: Also, you should be looking in `<cygwin/signal.h>` for the Cygwin signal header file.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. When grepping for `sigemptyset` there are two hits: (1) `/usr/include/bash/sig.h` and (2) `/usr/include/sys/signal.h`.

Comment: I didn't tell you to include `<cygwin/signal.h>` directly, instead it's a file you need to look at for Cygwin-specific things. Like for example what macros are needed to be defined before you include `<signal.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was worked through at [Botan 2.1.0 does not compile under Cygwin 2.8.0 with g++ 5.4.0](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/982). Here are the two comments of interest.

First, from [noloader](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/982#issuecomment-293312788):

> Cygwin uses Newlib, not GNU's `libstdc++`. When there's no
>   `-std=c++XX`, current GCC defaults to `-std=gnu++11` ([GCC 6 changes
>   to `gnu++14`](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) by default). I
>   believe GNU sources ensures expected functions, like `sigaction`, are
>   available.
>
> You might consider trying `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`  or
>   `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.
>
> Also see [C++ and feature guards Warning
>   Question](https://sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2017/msg00279.html) on the
>   Newlib mailing list.

Second, from [SideChannel](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/982#issuecomment-293498326):

> Thanks to @noloader. Until now `-std=c++11` was set in `Makefile`. The
>   important info is in above mentioned thread on the Newlib mailing
>   list. Yaakov Selkowitz wrote:
>
> > G++ defines `_GNU_SOURCE` on glibc targets, meaning that `-std=c++NN` is, contrary to the documentation, not strict ISO C++:
>
> So, applying the [patch #987](https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/987)
>   AND setting `-std=gnu++11` works for me. I
>   did not try the other `-D` options (I think the other fact is more
>   fundamental). Summarizing, @randombit please apply the PR #987 and set
>   `-std=gnu++11` for gcc under Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

The function is an extension over the ISO C standard.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html

as such is protected on  `/usr/include/sys/signal.h` by
__XSI_VISIBLE >= 4

see  `/usr/include/sys/features.h` for details.

As defaults the largest definition set is used, but `-std=XXX` reduces the definition scope

Comment: Thanks Matzeri. Its interesting the way the issue surfaces. It seems like everything should fail, or everything should succeed. At minimum, it seems like `-std=gnu++XX` should have compiled along with no `-std` since neither are ISO C. If I recall correctly, some `-std=gnu++XX` is a default when using GCC's C++ compiler.  I guess its the way newlib does things since its not present in libstdc++.

Comment: newlib headers are under re-shuffle. There were notable changes in the last months and `/usr/include/sys/features.h` provide the current guidelines.

Comment: so.... what's the solution?

Comment: @Rebroad `#define _GNU_SOURCE` should work to have the largest scope.